# Linear discriminant analysis matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, classification, lda

I want to do LDA classification on my data. My data has 6 features and I want to find out which one has the best classification performance. So My idea is to evaluate all the features separately and each time I only fit one feature into the LDA classifier in matlab function `fitcdiscr`.
My question is how can I visualize the output of the classification like the figure shown below:

[image]

After using the function `fitcdiscr`, I have a model and how can I visualize the line in the figure which seperates the two classes? should fit the feature together with the number of recordings to function `fitcdiscr`? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please explain more about your data, add some code to your post and clarify more about your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample data:

```
x = [1, 1.5] .* randn(100, 2);
x(51:end, :) = [1, 2] .* x(51:end, :) + [2, 4];
y = [ones(50, 1); 2*ones(50, 1)];
```

If you fit an LDA model with

```
mdl = fitcdiscr(x, y);
```

this returns an [`ClassificationDiscriminant`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationdiscriminant-class.html) object, which contains the field `Coeffs`, where all LDA coefficients are stored. This is a *k*-by-*k* structure, where *k* is the number of classes, i.e. here you have a *2*-by-*2* structure. `Coeffs(i, j)` contains the linear boundary between the classes `i` and `j`. Thus, we are only interested in `Coeffs(1, 2)`, i.e. the boundary between classes 1 and 2.

As described in the docs, the equation of the boundary between two classes is (simplified to ignore the quadratic part, as we are dealing with LDA and not QDA)

```
Const + Linear * x = 0,
```

Thus, we can calculate the function of the line with

```
x(2) = -(Const + Linear(1) * x(1)) / Linear(2)
```

We can create a scatter plot with `gscatter`, and add the line by finding the minimal and maximal x-Values of the current axis (`gca`) and calculating the corresponding y-Values with the equation above.

```
figure(1)
gscatter(x(:, 1), x(:, 2), y);
hold on

lx = get(gca, 'Xlim');
ly = -(mdl.Coeffs(1, 2).Const + mdl.Coeffs(1, 2).Linear(1) .* lx) / mdl.Coeffs(1, 2).Linear(2);
plot(lx, ly, '-b', 'DisplayName', 'LDA')

hold off
```

which results in

[image: Resulting plot: scatter plot of both classes and the LDA line]